# Filter a pattern in middle of a string of an array JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have an array, I want to filter out all the paths which are in form of `/__/:__Id`. I am currently using `.endsWith` property but I want to make a generic code which recognizes the pattern and doesn't return paths in pattern of /routename**/:nameId**

```js
const ROUTES = [ { path: "/" }, { path: "/faqs" }, { path: "/contactus" }, { path: "/pricing" }, { path: "/products" }, { path: "/careers/:jobId" }, { path: "/careers" }, { path: "/about-us" }, { path: "/features" }, { path: "/usecase/:usecaseId" } ];

const selectedRoutes = ROUTES.map( (item) => {
  if (item.path === "/")
    return "";
  else
    return item.path;
}).filter( (item) => { return !item.endsWith("Id")}); 

console.log(selectedRoutes)
```

Comment: Could you try to clarify the question and also the code a little? You say `I want to filter out all the paths which are in form of /__/:__Id` and then `doesn't return paths in pattern of /routename**/:nameId**` - these two statements seem to contradict each other - or I am misunderstand you. In any case; clarification would help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this requirement with the help of below `RegExp`

```
^\/(\\w)+\/:.*Id\/?$
```

`RegEx` explanation **:**

`^\/` - Match the string start with forward slash
`(\\w)+` - Matches the word characters (a-z, 0-9 and underscore), `+` is used to match the word one or more time. 
`\/?` - Matches zero or one forward slash
`$` - Denotes end of a string

Live Demo **:**

```js
const ROUTES = [ { path: "/" }, { path: "/faqs" }, { path: "/contactus" }, { path: "/pricing" }, { path: "/products" }, { path: "/careers/:jobId" }, { path: "/careers" }, { path: "/about-us" }, { path: "/features" }, { path: "/usecase/:usecaseId" } ];

const re = new RegExp('^\/(\\w)+\/:.*Id\/?$', 'i');

const selectedRoutes = ROUTES.filter((item) => {
  return !item.path.match(re)
});

console.log(selectedRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ROUTES = [ { path: "/" }, { path: "/faqs" }, { path: "/contactus" }, { path: "/pricing" }, { path: "/products" }, { path: "/careers/:jobId" }, { path: "/careers" }, { path: "/about-us" }, { path: "/features" }, { path: "/usecase/:usecaseId" } ];

const selectedRoutes = ROUTES.map( (item) => {
  if (item.path === "/")
    return "";
else
return item.path;
}).filter( (item) => { return !item.includes(":")}); 

console.log(selectedRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions (regexp)?

```js
const ROUTES = [ { path: "/" }, { path: "/faqs" }, { path: "/contactus" }, { path: "/pricing" }, { path: "/products" }, { path: "/careers/:jobId" }, { path: "/careers" }, { path: "/about-us" }, { path: "/features" }, { path: "/usecase/:usecaseId" } ];

const re = new RegExp('/.*/:.*Id', 'i');

const selectedRoutes = ROUTES.map((item) => {
  if (item.path === "/")
    return "";
  else
    return item.path;
}).filter((item) => {
  return !item.match(re)
});

console.log(selectedRoutes);
```